# Controller is not defined if added to separate file for dialog window in angular material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

The dialog window has a separate controller `ctrl2` and functionality, if I add it as chain to same ctrl it works but adding it in another file so that it can be used elsewhere it throws error

```
ng:areq] Argument 'ctrl2' is not a function, got undefined
```

Whats wrong in case 2 ?

**Case1: In same file (It works fine)**

**file1.ctrl.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app.mydev.module1',[])
        .controller('ctrl1', crtl1)
        .controller('ctrl2', ctrl2);
    /* @ngInject */
    function ctrl1($scope, $mdDialog) {
        var vm = this;
        $scope.showAdvanced = function(ev) {
            $mdDialog.show({
                templateUrl: 'app/mydev/mypage.tmpl.html',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                controller: 'ctrl2',
                controllerAs : 'vm',
                targetEvent: ev,
                clickOutsideToClose:true,
                fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
            })
                .then(function(answer) {
                    $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
                }, function() {
                    $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
                });
        };
    }

    /* @ngInject */
    function ctrl2($scope, $mdDialog) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.user = {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        };
    }
})();
```

**Case 2 : In separate file (It throws error)**

**File1.ctrl.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app.mydev.module1',[])
        .controller('ctrl1', crtl1);
    /* @ngInject */
    function ctrl1($scope, $mdDialog) {
        var vm = this;
        $scope.showAdvanced = function(ev) {
            $mdDialog.show({
                templateUrl: 'app/mydev/mypage.tmpl.html',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                controller: 'ctrl2',
                controllerAs : 'vm',
                targetEvent: ev,
                clickOutsideToClose:true,
                fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
            })
                .then(function(answer) {
                    $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
                }, function() {
                    $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
                });
        };
    }


})();
```

**File2.ctrl.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app.mydev.module1',[])
        .controller('ctrl2', ctrl2);

    /* @ngInject */
    function ctrl2($scope, $mdDialog) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.user = {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        };
    }
})();
```

Comment: What is the order in view?

Comment: Didn't get . 'Order in view ?' Like file1.tmpl.html (associated ctrl1) has to call a dialog window  (mypage.tmpl.html)

Comment: i mean how you have refered those controllers in the index file?

Comment: It gets minified and appended by gulp process.  If I create separate module they are working.

Comment: That could be the reason, just check without minifying

Comment: same error, if i create separate html file in case 2 and not use as dialog it works fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123043/discussion-between-atjoshi-and-sajeetharan).